# Define multiple launch configurations in VS Code basing on file extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a simple project that contains JS and PY files.

In my `launch.json` I want to define the launch configuration based on the file type so JS will be running with Node, while PY will be running with Python.

Is there such configuration in launch.json?

Comment: Why can't you just define 2 configurations and start whichever one you want?  Are you trying to do it with one keybinding?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) v1.6.2.

You can use the file path to select a replacement for the particular debugger.

If you use a Compound launch, containing the Python Debugger and the Node Debugger and replace the file with a dummy file if the extension does not match that debugger just starts and ends.

In the workspaceRoot/.vscode folder create an empty file called `dummy`.

Setup `launch.json` as

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Node File if .js",
      "program": "${input:file_if_js}"
    },
    {
      "name": "Python: Current File if .py",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${input:file_if_python}",
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    }

  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Python or Node",
      "configurations": ["Python: Current File if .py", "Node File if .js"]
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "file_if_python",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
      "args": {
        ".py": "${file}",
        ".js": "${workspaceFolder}\\.vscode\\dummy"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "file_if_js",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
      "args": {
        ".js": "${file}",
        ".py": "${workspaceFolder}\\.vscode\\dummy"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Adjust the directory separator if you use Linux/MacOS.